# How is the Gossip Protocol, which is used by IOTA, classified?

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, scalability

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol) says:

> It is useful to distinguish three prevailing styles of gossip protocol:
>
> - Dissemination protocols (or rumor-mongering protocols).
>
>   - Event dissemination protocols
>   - Background data dissemination protocols
> - Anti-entropy protocols
> - Protocols that compute aggregates.

Every single class of Gossip Protocol has its own effects on a network. For a better understanding of IOTA, I'd like to understand which Gossip Protocol is used in IOTA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that such classification is mainly a theoretical exercise. In practice, a concrete implementation of a gossip like protocol may have properties/features/characteristics coming from different families.

The gossip in IOTA is mainly in the family of *Background data dissemination protocols* were any new transaction is immediately broadcast to all neighbors.

It also have characteristics of the *anti-entropy family* in the sense that when a node detect that a transaction is missing (i.e. the branch or trunk of a new transaction): the node will ask for the missing tx to it's neighbors.

Comment: The wallet execute attachToTangle by doing the necessary PoW. The outcome will initiate iota_broadcastTransactions to neighbours. Others like relay/forward, reattach, rebroadcast instances also disseminate messages to neighbours. Apart from these, are there any other instances nodes need to disseminate messages to neighbours?